# PHP - Send image via MMS to mobile phone via PHP

Tags: php, email

How do I take an image found online and mail that via MMS as an image.

I have tried [Mail MIME](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) but I just get this error:

> [23-Aug-2015 19:39:06 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Mail_mimePart in /home/whatevertesting/public_html/test/mimePart.php on line 83

I'm basically look to see how this site does it: http://www.textport.com/send_picture.aspx

Text an image to phone.

---

What I tried:

I went to `https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/` and downloaded the [1.9.0 stable release](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/download/). which included

```
tests/test_Bug_20xxx.php
... (test bug goes on for a bit)
scripts/phail.php
Mail/mime.php
Mail/mimePart.php
```

Then I went to the example https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php and tried what was included however... the example did not provide `mail.php` and thus my code was:

```
<?php

echo "Sending MMS...";

error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'mime.php';
include 'mimePart.php';


$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = 'hello.txt';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
              'From'    => 'myemail@email.net',
              'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
              );

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
$mail->send('myemail@gmail.com', $hdrs, $body);

?>
```

Changed email... but you get the picture. `hello.txt` was also in the same directory and I moved `mime.php` and `mimePart.php` to the same directory as the code above.

And the error: `[23-Aug-2015 19:39:06 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mail_mimePart in /home/whatevertesting/public_html/test/mimePart.php on line 83` happened.

---

Removing `include 'mimePart.php';` gives me this:

```
[23-Aug-2015 21:31:18 America/Detroit] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Mail_mimePart::encodeHeader() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/test_user/public_html/example/mime.php on line 1333
[23-Aug-2015 21:31:18 America/Detroit] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Mail_mimePart::encodeHeader() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/test_user/public_html/example/mime.php on line 1333
[23-Aug-2015 21:31:18 America/Detroit] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Mail_mimePart::encodeHeader() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/test_user/public_html/example/mime.php on line 1333
[23-Aug-2015 21:31:18 America/Detroit] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Mail_mimePart::_explodeQuotedString() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/mimePart.php on line 842
[23-Aug-2015 21:31:18 America/Detroit] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Mail_mimePart::encodeHeader() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/test_user/public_html/example/mime.php on line 1333
[23-Aug-2015 21:31:18 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mail' not found in /home/test_user/public_html/example/mms.php on line 27
```

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

We have an API that lets you [send and receive MMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). Here's a code sample of how you would it using our [PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install):

```
<?php

// this line loads the library 
require('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 

$account_sid = '[AccountSid]'; 
$auth_token = '[AuthToken]'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => "+16518675309", 
    'From' => "+14158141829", 
    'Body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!", 
    'MediaUrl' => "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",  
));
```

Hope that helps!